# How to match two dataframe columns and return matching values on a separate column in Python?

Tags: python

I am a newbie in Python and I need some help.

I have 2 data frame containing a list of users with a list of recommended friends from two tables.

[image: Match DataFrame Columns and Return Matching Values]

I would like to achieve the following:

1. Sort the list of recommended friends by ascending order from 2 data frame for each user.

[image: Sort elements by ascending order]

2. Match the list of matching recommended friends from dataframe2 to dataframe1 for each user. Return only the matched values.

[image: End results for obtaining matching value for matching values]

I have tried my code but it didn't achieve the desired results.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

///load data from csv
df1 = pd.read_csv('CommonFriend.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('InfluenceFriend.csv')

print(df1)
print(df2)

///convert values to list to sort by recommended friends ID
df1.values.tolist()
df1.sort_values(by=['User','RecommendedFriends'])
df2.values.tolist()
df2.sort_values(by=['User','RecommendedFriends'])

///obtain only matched values from list of recommended friends from df1 and df2.
df3 = df1.merge(df2, how='inner', on='User')
/// return dataframe with user, matched recommendedfriends ID
print(df3)
```

Problem encountered:

1. The elements in each list are not sorted in ascending order.
2. While matching each elements through pandas merge with "inner-join". It seems that it is not able to read certain elements.

Updates: Below are the data frame header which cause some error in the code.
[image: DataFrame1 Header]
[image: DataFrame2 Header]

Comment: Are all the users in both dataframes, or is it possible that user x from df1 is not present in df2?

Comment: Hi there. All the users in both data frames are the same. Only the recommended friends are different from each table. I would like to see whether dataframe1 and dataframe2 has the same recommended friends.

Comment: is the 'user' column the index?

Comment: No. I did not set user as index. However, the users should be unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be the solution to your problem. You might have to change a few variables but you get the idea: you merge the two dataframes on the users, so you get a dataframe with both lists for each user. You then take the intersection of both lists and store that in a new column.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, [5, 7, 10, 11]], [2, [3, 8, 5, 12]]]),
                   columns=['User', 'Recommended friends'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, [5, 7, 9]], [2, [4, 7, 10]], [3, [15, 7, 9]]]),
                   columns=['User', 'Recommended friends'])

df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='User')
df3['intersection'] = [list(set(a).intersection(set(b))) for a, b in zip(df3['Recommended friends_x'], df3['Recommended friends_y'])]
```

Output `df3`:

```
    User    Recommended friends_x   Recommended friends_y   intersection
0   1       [5, 7, 10, 11]          [5, 7, 9]               [5, 7]
1   2       [3, 8, 5, 12]           [4, 7, 10]              []
```

Comment: Thanks but it gave me weird results though.

Comment: What do you mean with weird results?

Comment: intersection  
0   [9, 7, ], ,, 5, 6, 2, [, 8, 1, 4, 3, 0]  
1            [9, 7, ], ,, 2, [, 1, 4, 3, 0]  
2         [9, 5, ], ,, 7, 6, 2, [, 8, 1, 4]  
3   [9, 5, ], ,, 7, 6, 2, [, 8, 1, 4, 3, 0]  
4         [5, ], ,, 7, 6, 2, [, 1, 4, 3, 0]  
5         [9, 5, ], ,, 2, [, 8, 1, 4, 3, 0]'

Comment: Could you show how exactly your dataframes look like in Python? And what are the dtypes of your df (found by df.dtypes)?

Comment: User int64, RecommendedFriends object, dtype: object

Comment: @Ryan could you cut your dataframes so they only contain the first row, then output them as dict (with df.to_dict()) and paste both dataframes here? That way I have the exact dataframe as you, and I'm able to see where it goes wrong.

Comment: df1 results ----->  {'985': {}, '[736,979,851,987,980,976,972,7460,973,978]': {}}          df2 results ------> {'985': {}, '[987,736,854,16964,285,979,17685,972,851,7460]': {}}

Comment: @Ryan that formatting seems off. Anyhow, above code should work if your 'user' column is not the index, is int64, and the recommended friends column contains lists of integers. If you make sure your dataframes adhere to these requirements, you should be good.

Comment: Thanks . Which part should i correct on the formatting?

Comment: @Ryan if you could edit your original post with some images of the actual dataframes in Python (df.head()), I can possibly see what goes wrong.

Comment: I have uploaded the dataframe header for df1 and df2 on the original post.

Comment: @Ryan thanks. Did you make sure the columns are the same as in your dataframes? Other than that, the code above should definitely work since there are no differences.

Answer (score 0):

I do not quite understand what exactly your problem is, but in general you will have to assign the dataframe to itself again.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.read_csv('CommonFriend.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('InfluenceFriend.csv')

print(df1)
print(df2)

df1 = df1.values.tolist()
df1 = df1.sort_values(by=['User','RecommendedFriends'])
df2 = df2.values.tolist()
df2 = df2.sort_values(by=['User','RecommendedFriends'])

df3 = df1.merge(df2, how='inner', on='User')
print(df3)
```

Comment: This is not a solution to OP's question.